# OpenOPC Python - opc.properties are not received as expected

Tags: python

As per the explanation in the documentation([OpenOPC Documentation](http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html)), opc.properties('Testtest/test.test') should return a list of tuple(id, description, value) but this is only giving me value.

```
import OpenOPC
import time
import pywintypes


pywintypes.datetime = pywintypes.TimeType


opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('abc.xyz')


list_possible_turbines = opc.list(recursive=True)
print(list_possible_turbines)

while True:
    try:
        for i in range(1,6):
            print(opc.properties('Testtest/test.test', id=i))
    except:
        print('error')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Can someone help me here? I'm expecting an output like this:

```
[(1, 'Item Canonical DataType', 'VT_I4'), (2, 'Item Value', 491), (3, 'Item Quality', 'Good'), (4, 'Item Timestamp', '06/25/07 02:24:44'), (5, 'Item Access Rights', 'Read')]
```

instead of:

```
['VT_I4', 491, 'Good','06/25/07 02:24:44','Read]
```

Also, If I don't mention id:

```
while True:
    try:
        print(opc.properties(list_possible_turbines))
    except OpenOPC.TimeoutError:
        print('Timeout error')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UI585722/PycharmProjects/OPCDataRead/OPCRead/connect_data.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(opc.properties(list_possible_turbines))
  File "C:\Users\UI585722\PycharmProjects\OPCDataRead\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 1006, in properties
    return list(props)
  File "C:\Users\UI585722\PycharmProjects\OPCDataRead\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 938, in iproperties
    property_id = [p for p, d in tag_properties if p > 0]
  File "C:\Users\UI585722\PycharmProjects\OPCDataRead\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenOPC.py", line 938, in <listcomp>
    property_id = [p for p, d in tag_properties if p > 0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenOPC library was made up like that i guess and hence I created my own version to get a response that I wanted. Now even with every scenario it's returning a tuple (id, description, value) as described in the library.

Please find my version here:

[EditedVersion](https://github.com/dsb00715/OpenOPC.git)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting `id=`.

From the [docs](http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html) (emphasis mine):

> Requesting properties for a single item returns a list of (id, description, value) tuples. Each tuple in the list represents a single property.
>
> >>> opc.properties('Random.Int4')
>
> [(1, 'Item Canonical DataType', 'VT_I4'), (2, 'Item Value', 491), (3, 'Item Quality', 'Good'), (4, ...

and:

> The **optional id parameter** can be used to limit the returned value to that of a **single property**...
>
> >>> opc.properties('Random.Int4', id=1)
>
> 'VT_I4'

Comment: Please check update in the post! I can't update error message here: but if I try to run without mentioning id then it's throwing an error like this!